# How can user Enter time in a Text Field ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nstimer, nsdateformatter

I want user to enter time in a `TextField`. There are examples available to do it with a `DatePicker` but that consumes a lot of space in the app. When user taps on `TextField` he should enter `hh:mm`. Now there is a placeholder text but nothing to force user to enter in this format `hh:mm`
So how can I use `hh:mm` format in a `TextField`? OR in other words enter time in a text field.

Comment: u can also set textfeild input view as datepicker.

Comment: @AgentChocks. will it place a default text on it? So that user is restricted to enter `hh:mm` format?

Comment: The datePicker does take a lot of space, that is why the default behaviour you will see in most apps is to have the datePicker slide up from the bottom when a textfield or button is invoked. It allows the user to select a date and then slide down. Typically this is down with a semi-transparent view behind the datePicker to bring the user's focus to it. Asking the user to type the minutes / hours is quite unusual. In keeping with the iOS UX i'd advise you to go with a datePicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UITextField's shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` `delegate` method to format `hh:mm` format text in textfield

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound)
  {
    // BasicAlert(@"", @"This field accepts only numeric entries.");
    return NO;
  }
  else
  {
    NSString *text = textField.text;
    NSInteger length = text.length;
    BOOL shouldReplace = YES;

    if (![string isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        switch (length)
        {
            case 2:
                textField.text = [text stringByAppendingString:@":"];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        if (length > 4)
            shouldReplace = NO;
    }

    return shouldReplace;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the delegate method of the text field:-

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
  return YES;
 }
```

In this delegate method you can keep a check on the text that the user enters into the text field.

The `replacementString` gives you the character user is entering and `range` will give you the position where that character is being inserted.

And you can then, do the required formatting in the text field to make it look like **hh:mm** format that you want.

Also after doing this, you will need to use a `NSDateFormatter` to format the date accordingly into `NSDate`.

Keep in mind that you will need to perform checks for backspace too. As this delegate is called whenever a character is changed in the textfield.

Good Luck.

Any issues, feel free to ask

**EDIT**

If you do want to go through this hassle. You can simply set a datePicker as textField's input view. And on selecting a time, you can simply format the string that is being entered into the textField. Quite simple.

Comment: Setting the datePicker as the textField's input view is a great suggestion.  It worked seamlessly @Varij

Answer (score 0):

You can "force" user checking TextField.text (I named myself  pastetext )content after user completes it. First check the length of string. Then check formatting as bellow:

```
NSString *testtocheck= [[NSString alloc]init];
NSString *firstpart= [[NSString alloc]init]; // 00 - 23
NSString *firstpartisZero= [[NSString alloc]init]; // 01 - 09
NSString *myseparator= [[NSString alloc]init]; // @":"
NSString *secondpart= [[NSString alloc]init]; // 00 - 59
NSString *secondpartisZero= [[NSString alloc]init]; // 01 - 09
BOOL ok =NO;
testtocheck = self.pastetext.text;
if(testtocheck.length==0 || [testtocheck isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || [testtocheck isEqualToString:@""]||[testtocheck  isEqualToString:NULL]||[testtocheck isEqualToString:@"(null)"]||testtocheck==nil || [testtocheck isEqualToString:@"<null>"]){
    //   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: ....
    //      [alertView show];
} else if(testtocheck.length==5) {
    firstpart = [testtocheck substringToIndex:2];
    //now do the check
    int FIRSTval = [firstpart integerValue];

    firstpartisZero = [firstpart substringToIndex:1];
    int FIRSTvaliszero = [firstpartisZero integerValue];
              if(FIRSTvaliszero==0) {

        firstpart = [testtocheck  substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
        FIRSTval = [firstpart integerValue];
    } else {
         firstpart = [testtocheck substringToIndex:2];
         FIRSTval = [firstpart integerValue];
    }
    NSLog(@"FIRSTvaliszero %d",FIRSTvaliszero);

    if(FIRSTval>= 0 && FIRSTval <= 23) {
        ok =YES;
    } else {
        //   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: ....
        //      [alertView show];
        ok= NO;
    }

    if(ok) {
        myseparator = [testtocheck  substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)];
        if([myseparator isEqualToString:@":"]) {
            ok =YES;
        } else {
            //   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: ....
            //      [alertView show];
            ok= NO;
        }
    }
    if(ok) {
        secondpart =[testtocheck substringFromIndex:3];
        int SECONDval = [secondpart integerValue];
        secondpartisZero = [secondpart substringToIndex:1];
        int SECONDvaliszero = [secondpartisZero integerValue];

        if(SECONDvaliszero==0) {
            secondpart = [testtocheck substringFromIndex:4];
            SECONDval = [secondpart integerValue];
        } else {
            secondpart = [testtocheck substringToIndex:3];
            SECONDval = [secondpart integerValue];
        }
     NSLog(@"SECONDvaliszero %d",SECONDvaliszero);


        if(SECONDval>= 0 && SECONDval <= 59) {
            ok =YES;
        } else {
            //   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: ....
            //      [alertView show];
            ok= NO;
        }

    }
    if(ok) {
        //DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH self.pastetext.text
    } else {
        //   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: ....
        //      [alertView show];

    }
}
```

Maybe do some other checks for strict digit (numbers).

Answer (score 0):

I think not necessary to use datapicker. You can use valuepicker whereas it and you can do it any format. It helps to you valuepicker's delegate methods.